# Docusign template routing orders set to 1

Tags: json, docusignapi

I am sending a Docusign request as follows:

```
{
            "emailSubject": "Please Review Document and Electronically Sign",
                               "emailBlurb": "Please review documents and provide your electronic signature. test",
                               "enableWetSign": "false",
                               "status": "sent",
            "compositeTemplates": [
                {
                    "compositeTemplateId": "1",
                    "serverTemplates": [
                        {
                            "sequence": "1",
                            "templateId": "..."
                        }
                    ],
                    "inlineTemplates": [
                        {
                            "sequence": "2",
                            "documents":[
                                {
                                    "transformPdfFields": "true",
                                    "name": "...",
                                    "documentId": "1"
                                }],                                
                            "recipients": {
                                "signers": [
                                    {
                        "name":"Test1",
                        "email":"test1@gmail.com",
                        "note": "",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "routingOrder": "1",
                        "roleName": "Client 1",
                        "tabs": {...}
                    },{
                        "name":"test2",
                        "email":"test2@gmail.com",
                        "note": "",
                        "recipientId": "2",
                        "routingOrder": "2",
                        "roleName": "Client 2",
                        "tabs": {...}
                    },{
                        "name":"test3",
                        "email":"test3@gmail.com",
                        "note": "",
                        "recipientId": "3",
                        "routingOrder": "4",
                        "roleName": "Designated Registered Principal",
                        "tabs": {...}
                    },{
                        "name":"test4",
                        "email":"test4@gmail.com",
                        "note": "",
                        "recipientId": "4",
                        "routingOrder": "3",
                        "roleName": "Advisor",
                        "tabs": {...}
                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }]
                    }
            ]
        }
```

The problem I am having is that all the routing orders are being set to 1 when I send out the envelope. Some information behind this is that this is set up on a web server as a service, so the clients will use this service and a JSON like the one above is generated.

I can't find the reason why even though the routing orders are being set, that it sends it out to all recipients at the same time, setting the routing order to 1. This JSON is grabbed from right before the Docusign request is sent, so no modifications are made to the JSON after this point. Any ideas what could cause? Maybe a security setting?

**Note**: The ellipses are placeholders for the actual information there, so this is a valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved. This was working for some users, but not most of them. The problem was that the sequential signing (UI) wasn't checked for most of the users. Once I checked that option, it worked correctly.

This can be accessed from preferences and selected the users option on the left hand side.